# Let ... then ... in mathematical definition

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I am writing mathematical definitions in my scientific publications. My editor corrected the definitions in two different ways, but not consistently.

The editor is not from a publisher. It is a service that checks my punctuation and spelling, before I submit my paper for peer-review.

Now, I am not sure which version is correct:

Version 1:

> Let A, and B; then, C.

Version 2:

> Let A, and B. Then, C.

Version 3:

> Let A, and B; then C.

Version 4:

> Let A, and B, then C.

---

Edit: After reading

- https://www.grammarly.com/blog/semicolon/ seems to suggest that version 1 is correct.
- https://www.impan.pl/wydawnictwa/dla-autorow/errors.pdf suggests that version 2 is correct and version 4 is wrong.
- https://www.margieholdscourt.com/the-word-then-2/ seems to suggests that version 3 is correct.
- [Is it true you should never put a comma after "then"? Please explain](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236508/is-it-true-you-should-never-put-a-comma-after-then-please-explain) seems to suggest that version 3 is correct.
- https://linguaholic.com/linguablog/comma-before-then/ seems to suggests that version 4 is correct.
- [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/grammar.html#letthen](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ewest/grammar.html#letthen) suggests that version 4 is correct and version 2 is wrong.

Additionally I read

- [Semi-colon or comma before then?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461396/semi-colon-or-comma-before-then)
- http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/semi

In any case, I am none the wiser.

Comment: _A, B,_ and _C_ are not sufficient linguistic content to decide; sorry. A lot depends on the structure of the sentences that is being ignored. So maybe the changes were consistent to the editor. As long as they don't modify the symbolic logic you're presenting, punctuation marks, spaces, and capitalization -- even spelling -- are strictly in the province of the publisher.

Comment: @JohnLawler: The editor is not from a publisher. It is a service that checks my punctuation and spelling, before I submit my paper for peer-review. The contents is something like "Let x be a set, then a data object is an element of x." - does that help?

Comment: That would require a semicolon, since _Let x be a set_ is a sentence and requires a full stop like a semicolon or a period. You could specify several in a row with commas, like the old joke _Let F be a ring, let R be a group, and let G be a field_. But then you'd need a full stop.

Comment: Related? Or not really? [Is it wrong for a then clause to follow a since clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196941/is-it-wrong-for-a-then-clause-to-follow-a-since-clause)

Comment: @JohnLawler: So if the part before the "then" could be its own sentence, then I cannot use Version 4. But which of the other three should I use?

Comment: This "editor" probably doesn't have any idea what they are doing. They exist to take your money and give you bad advice. Get a different editor (or better yet, just send it straight to the scientific journal). Unless A is a very long phrase, you shouldn't need a comma in "Let A, and B"

Answer (score 3):

This is a *definition*?  That is: A,B is the setting and C is the actual definition?  If so: Definitely no comma after "then".  Probably a period after B (although semicolon or comma are OK).  If there are only two items A,B with "and" between, then no comma is needed.

> Let *n* be a positive integer and let *A* be an *n* x *n* matrix.  Then  *A* is said to be *singular* iff ...